# Moving objects from one Boost ptr_container to another

Tags: c++, boost, ptr-vector

I want to move certain element from a to b:

```
boost::ptr_vector<Foo> a, b;
// ...
b.push_back(a.release(a.begin() + i)));
```

The above code does not compile because the release function returns `boost::ptr_container_detail::static_move_ptr<...>`, which is not suitable for pushing back.

How should I proceed?

EDIT: I found out that the object returned has <strike>.get()</strike> `.release()` that provides a raw pointer (that may also lead to some exception safety issues). I would, however, prefer not relying on undocumented internal functionality, so feel free to share any better solutions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boost::ptr_vector<Foo> a, b;

// transfer one element a[i] to the end of b
b.transfer( b.end(), a.begin() + i, a ); 
// transfer N elements a[i]..a[i+N] to the end of b
b.transfer( b.end(), a.begin() + i, a.begin() + i + N, a );
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to use a std::vector<> of boost::shared_ptr (ie std::vector> a, b).

Then you can use the standard vectorfunctions.

Comment: That approach is simpler and arguably more robust, but the pointer containers are far more efficient if you need to juggle hundreds of thousands of objects.